# Is the Pi in reversed order Real number?

Tags: infinity, pi

**Pi** is real number. We can enumerate any digit of **Pi** number.

**Pi** has infinite number of digits and it's enumeration in base 10 starts as follow:

**Pi=3.14159265…**

What if we create the new number **n** from digits of **Pi** in reversed order? What if we will put every digit of **Pi** from float into natural part and from natural part into float. Reverse transformation works like mirror, the closest digits from float point will be mapped at the same distance into natural part and vice versa.

The new number **n** will looks like this:

**...56295141.3 = n**

The **n** will have infinite number of digits. We can enumerate any digit of this new number, but it has no first digit, similar as **Pi** which has no last digit.

Why it is allowed creation of numbers of infinite depth when we are going to smaller regions as **Pi**, but not allowed to create numbers of infinite size as **n**, where we are going to larger regions?

Number **n** can be written as infinite sum. How can we go beyond the real numbers, if we know that basic property of Real numbers is that if **a,b** are Real numbers then **a+b** is also Real number? We can write **n** as **0.3+1+4*10+1*100+5*1000...** At each point we are adding real number to real number and there is no point where we can go outside of real numbers. We can even divide this sum into smaller sub sums and each of that smaller part also should be within real numbers.

If **n** is real number then **n** without floating point part can be natural number. If we could create natural number of infinite size, then we can show that Cantor's diagonal proof will fail, because in such case we will be able to create natural number of infinite size. If natural numbers can have infinite size then, we can create with the same diagonal manipulation on infinite size natural numbers as Cantor did with infinite depth Real numbers.

Is the **n** within Real number set?

Comment: The limit of the sequence $0.3, 1.3, 41.3, 141.3, 5141.3, 95141.3,\dots$ is infinite and is thus not a real number.  It is larger than any real number.

Comment: n is not real. In fact, it's not a number at all. It's infinitely large.

Comment: @Kaynax: $n$ is a perfectly good [$10$-adic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).

Comment: Considering $0. \dots 56295141$ would be interessting. But this is still divergent but bounded.

Comment: @MrYouMath What does that string even mean, though? Both $\pi$ and "reversed $\pi$" make sense in the appropriate metrics on $\mathbb{Q}$ - I don't know what the thing you've described is supposed to be.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I don't know it either, I never studied math :). I just thought it would be interessting to start by $0.1$ then $0.41$ then $0.141$ and so forth ... and see what happens.

Comment: @MrYouMath Well, to argue that that string corresponds to something, the usual thing to do would be to show that those "approximations" "converge" to something in some sense (e.g. via a metric on $\mathbb{Q}$). However, there's no obvious sense in which those approximations should converge - so that's an obstacle to it meaning anything. That said, if you found a way to make sense of it, it could be cool.

Comment: @JMoravitz From the property of real numbers if a,b are real numbers then a+b is real number also. The number n can be written as a=0.3, b=1 => a+b=1.3; a=1.3, b=40 => a+b=41.3; a=41.3, b=100 => a+b=141.3 ... Each part of number n can be split into summation of two real numbers. Which a,b from Real numbers will make a+b not in Real numbers?

Comment: You seem to be confused about the fact that just because every number in a sequence has a property that the limit might not have that same property.  Just because every number in the sequence can be written as $a+b$ with $a$ and $b$ in the real numbers does not imply that the "*number*" you describe can be.

Comment: @JMoravitz  I am just asking where is the limit of **a** and **b** from real numbers which sums takes us outside of the real numbers.

Comment: There is no real number which when added to another real number results in a non-real number.  You are correct in saying when you add two real numbers you get another real number.  You are correct in saying that every number in the sequence I describe is real and that you can get the next number in the sequence by adding another real number.  Again, this does not imply that the limit of the sequence is real.  You cannot point to a specific place and say "here is where it breaks" because any finite point in the sequence you point to it is still real.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for answer. I don't say that this number is not infinitely large. This number is infinite and is bigger than anything we can imagine. It represent infinite process. Pi also cannot be enumerable and represent infinite process. We can put  each real number, small or large on the line as one point, and each such point has size zero. Why we can go with Pi infinitely deep into the smallest point 0 and we can't go infinitely large with the similar reversed process into the largest point of infinity? Why real numbers cannot be infinitely large?

Comment: infinity is not part of the real numbers.

Answer (score 19):

What you have doesn't make sense as a real number. However, within the $10$-adic numbers this does make sense. There aren't really any fancy properties one can divine about this number, but it certainly exists.

For any natural $n\geq2$, the $n$-adic numbers is like usual real numbers base $n$, except we allow infinitely many digits to the left and only finitely many digits to the right instead. Numbers are added and multiplied as "usual".

I should also add that the $10$-adic numbers aren't too common in use, for the simple reason that $10$ is not a prime. That fact gives the $10$-adic numbers some properties we like to avoid (specifically, division doesn't work).

Comment: If we will use instead of base 10, some base with prime number, will we be able to divide such prime-adic number?

Comment: @IvanSas Yes, the [$p$-adics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) for $p$ prime are much better. So working in base $p$ will be better for this.  (I worry that $p=2$ is suboptimal here, as it [so often is](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/915/is-there-a-high-concept-explanation-for-why-characteristic-2-is-special), but not greatly so - certainly all the basic algebraic properties still hold.)

Comment: The p-adics are not real numbers.  This is made clear in at least 3 separate instances in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Xodarap It is also strongly hinted at in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: @Arthur I would word it differently than "isn't a usual real number"; $\pi$, $e$, and $1729$ are also very unusual real numbers! I'm not sure if it is obvious for everyone that the first sentence means that it is not a real number at all.

Comment: @JiK Now that you say it, I see what you mean. I rephrased it to be less incorrect.

Answer (score 11):

Any real number has, by the [Archimedian Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) only finitely many digits before the dot. So no, this cannot be a real number.

Comment: Is this really a result of the Archimedian property? What algebraic structure *would* allow such a "number"?

Comment: @GFauxPas Are you familiar with the $10$-adics?

Comment: @GFauxPas A consequence of the Archimedian property is that for each positive real number $x$ you can find an integer $n$ such that $10^n \leq x < 10^{n+1}$. This means that $x$ has exactly $n$ digits.....

Comment: By that property, any real number has only finitely many digits after the dot, meaning $\pi$ wasn't real to begin with. I'm fine with that for practical definitions, but I think we're talking about the set of "real numbers" not things that are actually real.

Comment: @MichaelS That property does NOT imply finitely many digits after the dot....

Comment: There are an infinite number of digits of $\pi$ that are infinitely smaller than the first digit. Meaning the set of digits of $\pi$ is non-Archimedean.

Comment: @MichaelS The Archimedian property is a property of $\mathbb R$, you cannot start applying it to random sets.Moreover, the Archimedian property is about existence for ONE real number of a LARGER natural number, has nothing to do with infinitely many smaller numbers .... Finally, there is no such thing as infinitely many digits smaller than one digit, the only possible digits are $\{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, and no matter what the first digit is (in this case 1) there can only be 9 digits smaller than it.

Comment: Digits are not the same as numerals. In the number 4.44, the last digit has the same numeral as the first, but they are neither the same value nor the same digit. Also, the Archimedean property presumably applies to $\mathbb{R}$, but that's not its definition. As the Wikipedia article you linked states, it's a property that applies to various mathematical structures. Also note that the property is about either the existence of infinite comparisons, or, by the inverse math, infinitesimal comparison.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47544/discussion-between-michaels-and-n-s).

Comment: @MichaelS Even with this definition, none of the digits of $\pi$ is infinitely many times smaller than the first digit.Any digit of $\pi$, multiplied by the right power of $10$ becomes larger than $\pi$..

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$ be the sequence of digits of $\pi$: $a_0 = 3$, $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 4$, $a_3 = 1$, etc such that $$\pi = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k 10^{-k}.$$

Now define the sequence
$$r_n = \frac{1}{10} \sum_{k=0}^n a_k 10^k,$$
of which the first elements are $r_0 = 0.3$, $r_1 = 1.3$, $r_2 = 41.3$, etc.

Your question is whether $$\lim_{n \to \infty} r_n$$ exists.

The answer is *no*, as this is clearly a divergent sequence.
For the proof, suppose you claim that $L$ is the limit, and it is a real number with $n$ digits before the decimal point (that is, let $n = \lceil \log_{10} L \rceil$). Then I claim that $r_{n+2} > L$.

Comment: Pi is irrational and has no finite **n** number of digits, so the reversed one will also have not the finite number of digits. I don't know why it's allowed to have infinite sequence in floating point part, but finite one in natural part. We can do one to one mapping from Pi digits to the natural numbers,  so the Pi itself is not bigger than natural numbers. It is like that, we can do infinitely many times zoom in closer and closer, but we can't do the opposite infinite process which for zoom out to the larger and larger.